# Change PHP Variable to Lowercase

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$color_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_color-shade');
foreach ( $color_values as $color_value ) {
   echo $color_value->name;
}
echo $color_value->name;
```

The above outputs for example: Red

I'd like it to echo: red

And can't change the underlying data in the database, and also changing it via css text transform wouldn't help in my particular use case. So hoping to do this in the above code.

Tried for instance:

```
$color_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_color-shade');
foreach ( $color_values as $color_value ) {
   echo $color_value->name;
}
$color_value->name = strtolower($color_value->name);
echo $color_value->name;
```

But still shows as Red instead of red. What might I be missing?

Comment: @cchiera can you share `print_r($color_values)` ?

Comment: @SahilGulati Sure: Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 391 [name] => medium [slug] => color-medium [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 391 [taxonomy] => pa_color-shade [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 13 [filter] => raw ) )

Comment: How is `$color_values` related to `$color_value`?

Comment: are you doing this in loop?

Comment: @Barmar Thats what i was thinking... Might that object does not have such value or something else is wrong.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Forgot to paste in an extra line that shows show color_values connects to color_value here on SO. Have updated accordingly.

Comment: It looks like you're iterating them all without changing the case, then changing the case of the last item after the loop and outputting that. Is that what you had in mind? Seems like you just need to `echo strtolower($color_value->name);` _inside the loop_.

Comment: @cchiera but still there is no key in your object with name `name`. `$color_value->name`

Comment: @Barmar This is a WordPress (WooCommerce) site an one of the product attributes is "pa_color-shade". For one product that value may be Red for another product it may be Blue. Etc.

Comment: @SahilGulati in the output right after it says "391" it says [name] => medium They key is name and the object is medium correct?

Comment: @SahilGulati WP_Term has a `__get()` magic method.

Comment: @Barmar no typos to my knowledge The color values with and without an s is intentional. There was an extra for each that didn't include here from the original code that I've pasted in so that should help explain. Everything works with the existing code, only issue is making the echo lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `name` isn't a real property in the object, so WP is creating it on the fly, probably using a `__get` magic method, so you can't modify that property. Use a separate variable.

```
$color = strtolower($color_value->name);
echo $color;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Leave it up to WordPress to make some simple php more complicated the debug. Appreciate your help.